# What does "It is a means to an end, not an end in itself" mean?

Tags: meaning

English is not my native language and I'm struggling to get the meanings of:

1. It is a means to an end, not an end in itself.
2. It is more of a means to an end rather than an end in itself.

I'd highly appreciate if someone explain the meanings of these two sentences to me. Thanks

Comment: Did you look up *means* and *end* in a dictionary?  We don't mind helping if a definition is difficult to understand, but would rather not be used as a substitute for research.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Means_to_an_end

Comment: Might be more appropriate on philosophy.SE

Comment: @Mitch  Philosophy if the OP was a native speaker. Clearly this is the case for ELL to handle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An "end" or "end in itself" is the end result, the ultimate goal, the final conclusion.  A "means to an end", therefore, is a way of getting to a given goal.

So for example, if I want to lose ten pounds, I might start running to lose weight.  For me, running is a means (the very act of running) to an end (losing the weight).  I could also start dieting; I don't want to eat less but it is a means to an end.  If, however, I actually like running, the act of running is itself the end, so the expression would not be appropriate.

A related expression is "The ends justify the means."  This phrase is used when the end result justifies whatever action was used to get there.  The main character in a movie who wants to avenge a murdered loved one might go on a killing rampage to get at the murderer, and you might say that for her, the ends justified the means.

Answer (score 6):

The idiom "A means to an end" differentiates between an end goal and the means or methods and actions used to reach that goal.

If I wanted to *get a job*, a means to that end might be *writing my resume*.  When I found a job my end would be achieved, the goal I had in mind. But the end was never to write myself a good resume, that was only a means to the end, getting a job.